# how can i send multiple data from controller to page html using ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

in my page i used ajax to get data from db, so in my controller i retrieve two data by when i send them to page i get just one data

this is a method ajax that i used

```
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url:'{!!URL::to('gestion_commandes/create/gencodesol1')!!}',
    data:{'id':type, 'id':code},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.nbrdebut);
        //console.log(data.type);

      /* var codesol=data+data.nombre;
        for(y=1;y<=nbrrowsol;y++ ){
           var somme=codesol+y;
        $('#codesol'+y).val(somme);
        console.log(somme);
        }*/
    },
    error:function(){

    }
});
```

this is my function in controller

```
 public function findnaturesol1(Request $request)
    {
        $data=Commande::select('nombre')->where('code', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->id.'%')->count();
        if($data!=0){
            //$data1=Commande::select('select code from commandes ')->where('code','LIKE', '%'.$request->id.'%')->count();

           // $data=Matrice::select('nbrdebut')->where('type',$request->id)->first(); 
           //  $data=$vide1+$data2;
           // echo '$data2->$nbrdebut';
            return response()->json($data);
        }
        /*else{
            $data=DB::table('commandes')-insertGetId(['code' => 'first']);
        }*/


    }
```

Comment: same probleme when i send just one id

Comment: not working, my problem is how to get from controller 2 data  like using an array in return response...

Answer (score 0):

this is my code sorry i forgot the comment mark

```
public function findnaturesol1(Request $request)
    {
        $data=Commande::select('nombre')->where('code', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->id.'%')->count();
        if($data!=0){
            //$data1=Commande::select('select code from commandes ')->where('code','LIKE', '%'.$request->id.'%')->count();

            $data=Matrice::select('nbrdebut')->where('type',$request->id)->first(); 
           //  $data=$vide1+$data2;
           // echo '$data2->$nbrdebut';
            return response()->json($data);
        }
        /*else{
            $data=DB::table('commandes')-insertGetId(['code' => 'first']);
        }*/


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
public function findnaturesol1(Request $request)
    {
        $data=Commande::select('nombre')->where('code', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->id.'%')->count();
        if($data!=0){

            $data1 = Commande::select('select code from commandes ')->where('code','LIKE', '%'.$request->id.'%')->count();

            $data2 = Matrice::select('nbrdebut')->where('type',$request->id)->first(); 

            $data = [
                 'data1' => $data1,
                 'data2' => $data2
            ];
            return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
        }

    }
```

In js:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url:'{!!URL::to('gestion_commandes/create/gencodesol1')!!}',
    data:{'id':type, 'id':code},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(response){
        console.log('data1::', response.data.data1);
        console.log('data2::', response.data.data2);
    },
    error:function(){

    }
});
```